# Docker mapped port is not accessible outside

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nuxt.js

I'm running:

`sudo docker run -d -p 9001:9001 --rm --name <cname> <img>`

then I go to my browser at `localhost:9001`, no connection.

If I run:

`sudo docker run -d --network=host --rm --name <cname> <img>`

I can access the application at `localhost:9001` from my browser.

Running the first command, I can verify it's running properly inside docker by running:

`sudo docker exec <cname> wget localhost:9001` which returns a page as expected.

If it is useful: the application running is a standard `nuxt.js` that listens on port `9001`, the dockerfile used to generate the image is (ran npm build before docker image build)

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app/
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 9001

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

The docker version I'm using is `19.03.8-ce`. How would I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running docker without sudo. Using docker with sudo is not a good practice and can cause a lot of troubles.

To use docker without sudo, you should add yourself to "docker" group, as stated in official documentation.

> To create the docker group and add your user:

```
Create the docker group.

$ sudo groupadd docker

Add your user to the docker group.

$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
```

[Docker post-install documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)